# Multiple dropdownlist's items clicks in Spinner

Tags: android, overriding, android-spinner

When U click on selected item in dropdown spinner's list spinner dont call onItemSelected method. I need to do multiple spinner's items clicks so I try to create my own spinner. Help me pls to do this thing. Maybe I need to `@Override` some methods in AdapterView or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MySpinner extends Spinner {

    public MySpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (sameSelected) {
            // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (sameSelected) {
            // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }
    }
}
```